# Oracle Stored procedure - NOT IN (SUBQUERY) CONSUMES A LOT OF TIME

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle procedure which does the same work as following:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE My_TEST_PROCEDURE
(
   cur out sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
  open cur for
   SELECT * FROM MYTABLE1
   WHERE MYTABLE1.SOMEROWNAME NOT IN 
        (SELECT SOMEROWNAME FROM MYTABLE2);
END My_TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

But there are a lot of data in this two tables, approximately 300000 rows in each. So it takes a plenty of time to finish. What can I do to decrease that amount of time. I have tried declaring a sys_refcursor and reading data into this cursor as following:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE My_TEST_PROCEDURE
(
   cur out sys_refcursor
)
IS
DECLARE EXISTING_ITEMS SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN EXISTING_ITEMS FOR
    SELECT SOMEROWNAME FROM MYTABLE2;
  open cur for
   SELECT * FROM MYTABLE1
   WHERE MYTABLE1.SOMEROWNAME NOT IN 
        EXISTING_ITEMS;
END My_TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

But this time ORA-00932 error occurs. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many non-matching records does the query produce? How long is "plenty of time"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a query with join like below:

```
SELECT MYTABLE1.* 
FROM   MYTABLE1 
       left join MYTABLE2 
              ON MYTABLE1.SOMEROWNAME = MYTABLE2.SOMEROWNAME 
WHERE  MYTABLE2.SOMEROWNAME IS NULL
```

Comment: What difference would it make?

Comment: thank you for quick reply. But I don't have any null data in table2. mytable2 is a log file, and I am adding ID-s from myTable1 to log table when they are sent, and I want to select items from myTable1 which are not sent. I am using Log table because I must not add another column to myTable1

Comment: MYTABLE2.SOMEROWNAME will have null data for the rows in MyTable1 that have no matching record in MyTable2.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using *, specify columns names.

Why your're using a cursor? What you're doing can be achieved using a left outer join where b.mycolumn is null

Best regards.